# MATLAB does not define vector for a specific function when I use a vector as an input

Tags: matlab, vector

The code block is the following

```
V=0:30
Gacc=V.^2/(g*L+Kus*V.^2)
Gyaw=V./(L+Kus*(V.^2/g))
```

I can perfectly get Gyaw as a vector but for Gacc I only get a scalar for the final input V=30.
I tried it in a for loop and saw that it can calculate but somehow I only get the last one.
How do I assign them to a vector?

g=9.81, L=2.794 and Kus=0.026294 all constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the other variables are scalars, and only V is a vector, I think you forgot a dot before the division.

`Gacc=(V.^2)./(g*L+Kus*V.^2)`